# Get ID from URL in an action from a controller with ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, action

I work asp.net MVC, I call an action (let's call it *MyAction*) from *MyController* while I'm at the following **url www.mywebapp.com/MyController/AnotherAction/123**

I need to get the **123** in *MyAction*, so I started to do something like this :

```
var url = Request.Url;
```

In order to parse it then get the ID.

But I'm not sure if it's the "best" way to do it. Do you know how can I get the ID from the current URL when I am in *MyAction* properly and safely ?

Comment: why you don't create a parameter for your Action to get this data

Comment: @Arjuna My action is created by an external library, I'm not sure if I can add another parameter and I don't know how to add it with this library

Answer (score 9):

You can get this from the `RouteData`:

```
var url = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id from URI Like This:

---

Cotroller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
//if you want use in view you can save id in view bag
        ViewBag.ID = id;
        Your Code......
        return View(...);
    }
```

---

and in view use of view bag

View:

```
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var ID = ViewBag.ID;
}
```

---

Now you have an ID in the variable